# Have error from running .net Core v 2.0

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

i have some problem.
When i run in Nuget Pacages command:

> ### dotnet run

or another command from dotnet packages, i get error like a:

> ### dotnet.exe : ЌҐ г¤ «®бм ­ ©вЁ ўлЇ®«­пҐ¬л© Їа®ҐЄв. “ЎҐ¤ЁвҐбм ў в®¬, зв® Їа®ҐЄв бгйҐбвўгҐв ў E:\WebApplication7, Ё«Ё ЇҐаҐ¤ ©вҐ Їгвм Є Їа®ҐЄвг б Ї®¬®ймо --project.
>
> - dotnet run
>
>   - CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (ЌҐ г¤ «®бм ­ ©в...®ймо --project.:String) [], RemoteException
>   - FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError##

Comment: I've decoded text with [this tool](https://www.artlebedev.ru/decoder/). Message is in russian, this is my translation: "Can't find executable project. Check that project exists into E:\WebApplication7 or specify path to project with --project"

Comment: So you need to use `dotnet run --project .\src\MyProject\ `  or invoke `dotnet run` from inside the project folder.